# In MVVM Community Toolkit VM I load a Person(with 20 observable props), in V I display Person's data. How to enable SaveButton on any data changes?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, windows-community-toolkit, relaycommand, canexecute

I have a model

```
public partial class Patient : GenericEntity
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int genderId;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Crucials))]
    private string lastName = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Crucials))]
    private string firstName = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string fatherName = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Crucials))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Age))]
    private DateTime _DOB = DateTime.Now;

    [NotMapped]
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            //DateOnly currentDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
            DateTime currentDate =DateTime.Now;
            int age = currentDate.Year - DOB.Year;

            // Check if the current date is before the birth date
            if (currentDate < DOB.AddYears(age))
            {
                age--;
            }

            return age;
        }
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _address = "";
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _city = "";
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _country = "";
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _tel1 = "";
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _tel2 = "";
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _email = "";
  
   //(15 more fields are following all of them decorated with [ObservableProperty])
}
```

The viewmodel is as follows

public partial class PatientViewModel : ObservableObject
{
private bool _patientPropertyChanged = false;

```
private AppDbContext _db;

private readonly PatientRepository _patientRepository;
private readonly NATreeNodeRepository _natreenodeRepository;

private Patient? patient;

[ObservableProperty]
private int _patientId = 0;

[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSaveChanges), IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
private async Task SaveChanges(CancellationToken token)
{
    var hasChanges = _db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
    if (hasChanges)
    {
        try
        {
            // Update the Patient's registration date to DateTime.Now
            if (Patient != null)
            {
                Patient.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            }

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            MessageBox.Show("Changes successfully saved to the database!");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Saved changes");
}
```

}

```
private bool CanSaveChanges() => PatientPropertyChanged;



public PatientViewModel(int patientId)
{
    _db = new();

    _patientRepository = new PatientRepository(_db);
    _natreenodeRepository = new NATreeNodeRepository(_db);

    PatientId = patientId;

    InitializeAsync(PatientId);

    _patientPropertyChanged = false;
}

private async void InitializeAsync(int patientId)
{
    try
    {
                                                                                        // Retrieve the patient with the given ID from the repository
        Patient = await Task.Run(() => _patientRepository.Get(patientId)); // Replace with your repository method

        // Check if patient is null or doesn't exist
        if (Patient == null)
        {
            Patient = new()
            {
            };
            _patientRepository.Add(Patient);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

}

The PersonView window contains several controls (one for each of the person's properties) and a, initially disabled, SaveButton bound to a RelayCommand SaveCommand

My question is how can someone enable or disable the save button when any of the Person's properties is changed by the user on this window.

As I am stuck I can not find any solution to this question.

There is a solution if the Person contains 2-3 properties. But when it contains many then I can not come up with a clever solution that could avoid repeating blocks of code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 - Use Database

As I understand the capabilities of you Database you may delegate this to your database, as `_db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` seams to check if there are changes. So you may change `CanSaveChanges()`to

```
private bool CanSaveChanges() => _db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
```

## Solution 2 - Use PropertyChanged Event

Otherwise if you database can not check for changes this you may use the PropertyChanged Event like:

```
// Properties for Patient and Changed State
[ObservableProperty] private bool _patientPropertyChanged;
[ObservableProperty] private Patient _patient;

public bool CanSaveChanges() => PatientPropertyChanged;

private async void InitializeAsync(int patientId)
{
    try
    {
         if (Patient == null)
        {
            Patient = new()
            {
            };
            _patientRepository.Add(Patient);
        }

        //Add Event Handle to set changed
        Patient.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => 
        {
            //You may filter here for relevant changes
            PatientPropertyChanged = true;
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSaveChanges), IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
private async Task SaveChanges(CancellationToken token)
{
    var hasChanges = _db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
    if (hasChanges)
    {
        //..
    }
    //Reset changed Satte
    PatientPropertyChanged = false;
}
```

Comment: the first solution is not what I am looking for. 
When you have a window with several controls on it (displaying and bound to the Person's object) and you want the SaveButton to get enabled when the data of any of them changes there is no mechanism to reach to the _db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() 
Thanks anyway

Comment: the solution 2 works partially.. It only works when the user moves the cursor to another control. Then the Save button enables once changes have made. But the Save button remains inactive while the user changes the contents of the control. Only when he moves out of the control the save button enables. Can someone help with that?

Comment: For that you need to change the ```UpdateSourceTrigger``` of your Binding to ```PropertyChanged```  like ```<TextBoxMargin="5 2" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>``` the default is to update the Property on FocusLeft but you need to Update the Property imidiately.

Comment: Great!! This is it!! I am about to mark your answer as the correct one as it works like a charm. 
Just a small detail to clarify. On my window there is a datepicker also!! When i use the dropdown to select a date everything continues to work like a charm
But when i type or alter the date by typing, the save button does not change to enabled even though the date is a valid one. Is there a similar 
"UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"
for the datetime? Thanks Daniel You are a star!!

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577176/editable-combobox-binding-and-update-source-trigger

Answer (score 1):

You should raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event for the command whenever the `PatientPropertyChanged` property is set.

In the MVVM toolkit, you can do this by applying the `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor]` attribute to the backing field for the property:

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SaveChangesCommand))]
private bool _patientPropertyChanged;
```

Comment: You are correct!! I had already done that but it had not included in my copy/paste to this page!! It is necessary though that's why I pressed the up arrow. Thanks mm8