# ComboBox.Text shows always null?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to get a text from my `ComboBox` in order to switch it, but it always returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```xaml
<ComboBox Name="cbForms" SelectionChanged="cbForms_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Polygon</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Rechteck</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Dreieck</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Kreis</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

C# Code:

```cs
private void cbForms_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = cbForms.Text;
    switch (text)
    {
        case "Polygon":
            {
                commandText = "SELECT f.bezeichnung, t.X, t.Y, t.id FROM figure05 f, TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(f.shape)) t";
                lblAnz.Content = anzPolygon.ToString();
                break;
            }
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961118/combobox-selectionchanged-event-has-old-value-not-new-value

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `Binding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void cbForms_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cbForms != null)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = cbForms.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (item != null && item.Content != null)
        {
            string text = item.Content.ToString();
            switch (text)
            {
                case "Polygon":
                    {
                        commandText = "SELECT f.bezeichnung, t.X, t.Y, t.id FROM figure05 f, TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(f.shape)) t";
                        lblAnz.Content = anzPolygon.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want it to work initially before you have selected any item, you should set the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox` instead of setting the `IsSelected` property of the `ComboBoxItem`:

```xaml
<ComboBox Name="cbForms" SelectionChanged="cbForms_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,289,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"
          SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBoxItem>Polygon</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Rechteck</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Dreieck</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Kreis</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: But it won't work on initial selection (`item.Content` will be null while really `Polygon` item is selected).

Comment: The first call of event handler happens due to `IsSelected = true` of one of combox items. During this call `Content` is `null` probably due to way how view is constructed. This has to be handled separately I guess. Another thing: `cbForm` and `item` null-checks, they are not needed.

Comment: That's just a matter of setting the SelectedIndex property. See my edit.