# WPF - combobox with IF statement

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have little problem with comboBox and if statment.
On WindowsForm it's working but on WPF is working bad ;/
When i select "Standard" nothing is doing, when i select "PhoneBinding" lbl and text box is Visible, not hidden... what i doing wrong ?

This is code:

```
private void cmbProces_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (cmbProces.Text == "Standard")
        {
            lblUlica.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtUlicaFormatka.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        else if (cmbProces.Text == "Promesa")
        {
            lblUlica.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtUlicaFormatka.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (cmbProces.Text == "PhoneBinding")
        {
            lblUlica.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            txtUlicaFormatka.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

    }
```

I try also something like that:

```
if (cmbProces.SelectedValue == "Standard")
        {
            lblUlica.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtUlicaFormatka.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        else if (cmbProces.SelectedValue == "Promesa")
        {
            lblUlica.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            txtUlicaFormatka.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (cmbProces.SelectedValue == "PhoneBinding")
        {
            lblUlica.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            txtUlicaFormatka.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

    }
```

But also not working... Can anybody tell what is wrong ?

Comment: Find out how you're populating your own ComboBox. Use the debugger to find out what SelectedValue is equal to. That's the property you want, not Text.

Comment: *"On WindowsForm it's working but on WPF is working bad"* - you are trying to do it *winformish* way in wpf, so you must suffer and on occasion discover existence of bindings, command, triggers and whole MVVM world full of wonders.

Comment: We need to know a bit more about the combo box and how your filling it.  Without the xaml and code used to populate the combo box I don't think we can give you very much help. [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox-wpf) is a quick tutorial on wpf combo boxes with basic strings [and this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-combobox/) shows a more indepth tutorial with custom objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox- SelectionChanged event has old value, not new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961118/combobox-selectionchanged-event-has-old-value-not-new-value)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution....
i add Items after InitializeComponent();

```
cmbProces.Items.Add("Standard");
cmbProces.Items.Add("Promesa");
cmbProces.Items.Add("PhoneBinding");
```

And delete in xaml file:

```
<ComboBoxItems>Standard</ComboBoxItems>
<ComboBoxItems>Promesa</ComboBoxItems>
<ComboBoxItems>PhoneBinding</ComboBoxItems>
```

And that's work for me :)

Sorry if my question was stupid but I start in WPF